# jquery ajax 1.4.2's ifModified workaround?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a script that looks like this :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
   setInterval(function() {
   $.ajax({ 
              url: "../Ps/th.php",
              ifModified:true, 
              success: function(data, textStatus){
   if(textStatus!="notmodified") {
   $("#display").append(data);
   alert(textStatus);
   }
   }});


  },1000);
  });
        </script>
```

and corresponding php is just this :

```
<?php
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT, true, 304");
echo "shrinath<br>";
?>
```

the ifModified header seems to be not working as documented (known bug/whatever).

How do i make sure that the ajax doesn't append the data if it is not changed ?

Comment: `.append(data);` - what is `data` here? html tags? JSON? just plain texts?

Comment: the php is shown in code, its echoing "shrinath<br>" thats the data coming to ajax..

Comment: most of the time, its going to be plain text/html

Comment: the lastmodified timestamp is itself flawed, you set it up in a way that makes the page seem to be updated every second...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its a bug in 1.4.2 : http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-1-3-2-update-to-1-4-2-ifmodified-option-doesn-t-still-work

EDIT :
hey i think php script is wrong check it out here : http://helpdesk.toitl.com/?w=ajax_ifModified check the loaded.php and index.html on the top right corner

Comment: I know it is a bug, I just wanna know if any brilliant thinkers here can come up with a good workaround here :)

Comment: you could echo gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") in a hidden div and use it for success method compare the values and then choose to append or not

Comment: could you post an example ? (just being lazy :) )

Comment: man, even then, his example too isn't working.. even after you modify the content it doesn't change... and atleast once it should show the modified content right ??

Comment: never mind, I did with a work around.. Not exactly the required type, but serves my purpose... I wanted to show the log of a server process, from a txt file, so I created a file reader script, now I am just reloading the data, not appending it...